# printing no. of times a link is used in DOM using JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a JS function which collects all the anchor tag or `<a>` tags from a webpage and displays the specific link in the console but the problem is that, if a link is used 2 or more times it does not print it on the console and displays the number of times it is used for example:-

This is my JavaScript Code:-

```
let link = document.querySelectorAll("a");

Array.from(link).forEach(function (element) {
let str = element.toString();
if (str==='https://www.javascript.com/') {
    console.log(`Your link is ${str}`);
    
}
})
```

Using this code, since the link `https://www.javascript.com/` came 2 times in the DOM
it displayed number 2 in front of the `console.log` command like this:-
[image: here number 2 is displayed]

here number 2 is displayed
all I want to do is remove that number **2** and paste it at the and of the code
by any method

Kindly tell me what changes I have to do to make this happen

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem about your code.
Chrome collapses consecutive rows that are identical.

With the settings button in the top right corner (->Preferences) of the console you can enable 'Show timestamps' which will put them on different lines.

[image]

You could also add something unique in each of the messages, like an ID or something that counts up. This will have the same effect, as the rows are not identical anymore then.

Comment: thnx for your answer I didn't had any Idea about this even though I didn't even thought about this . Don't mind if I ask you some more thing . I want to the the exact number of times that link was used without showing it as many times as it has been used , can you tell me how can I write the number of times this links was used (I don't want that number 2 icon type thing). I want to write it on the console.log command. How can I do that